# Write to OutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream

I'm trying to interact with a command line application using OutputStream. Running the command for the app:

```
Process pr = rt.exec(
    executor.getTool()
            + execProcess.getToolSuffixes().get(execProcess.getSystem().getName())
            + " "
            + executor.nextStep());
```

The app starts and waiting for some input, so I'm trying to write to the output of the proccess (pass other arguments).

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(pr.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

while (in.read() != -1) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    logger.debug("input read:{}", s);
    if (s.contains("delimiter:")) {
        String write =executor.nextStep();
        logger.debug(write);
        out.println(write);
        out.flush();
    }
}
out.close();
returnCode = pr.waitFor();
```

The `if` condition passes and it from logs it seems that it works.
The app generates the file as expected, it should contain passed arguments, but it's empty (it works when running manually)

Comment: out seems to be the outputstream for the process pr, are you sure it goes to a file?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. I guess I’m trying to write data to process which should be correct.